# Why is python's built in multiplication so fast

Tags: python, algorithm

So the other day I was trying something in python, I was trying to write a custom multiplication function in python

```
def multi(x, y):
    z = 0
    while y > 0:
        z = z + x
        y = y - 1
    return z
```

However, when I ran it with extremely large numbers like (1 << 90) and (1 << 45) which is (2 ^ 90) * (2 ^ 45). It took forever to compute.
So I tried looking into different types of multiplication, like the russian peasant multiplication technique, implemented down there, which was extremely fast but not as readable as multi(x, y)

```
def russian_peasant(x, y):
    z = 0
    while y > 0:
        if y % 2 == 1: z = z + x
        x = x << 1
        y = y >> 1
    return z
```

What I want you to answer is how do programming languages like python multiply numbers ?

Answer (score 18):

Your `multi` version runs in O(N) whereas `russian_peasant` version runs in O(logN), which is far better than O(N).

To realize how fast your `russian_peasant` version is, check this out

```
from math import log
print round(log(100000000, 2))   # 27.0
```

So, the loop has to be executed just 27 times, but your `multi` version's while loop has to be executed 100000000 times, when `y` is 100000000.

To answer your other question,

> What I want you to answer is how do programming languages like python
>   multiply numbers ?

Python uses [O(N^2) grade school multiplication algorithm for small numbers](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b514339e41ef/Objects/longobject.c#l2570), but for [big numbers it uses Karatsuba algorithm](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/b514339e41ef/Objects/longobject.c#l2694).

Basically multiplication is handled in C code, which can be compiled to machine code and executed faster.

Comment: BTW, according to Wikipedia, Toom-Cook algorithm is faster than Karatsuba, and Schönhage–Strassen algorithm is even way faster than Toom-Cook. I'm just curious, anybody knows the reason behind choosing the Karatsuba algorithm in Python (for big numbers)?

Comment: @oski86 Those other algorithms essentially trade multiplications for some combination of adds, subs, shifts, and even constant divisions. Especially on modern processors, these algorithms only provide benefits at very high precision. On the Z80 and other older processors, the divisions that occur in other Toom-Cook algorithms render it less efficient than a clever implementation of Karatsuba, or even FFT/Schönhage–Strassen.

Answer (score 6):

Programming languages like Python use the multiplication instruction provided by your computer's CPU.

In addition, you have to remember that Python is a very high-level programming language, which runs on a virtual machine which itself runs on your computer. As such, it is, inherently, a few order of magnitudes slower than native code. Translating your algorithm to assembly (or even to C) would result in a massive speedup -- although it'd still be slower than the CPU's multiplication operation.

On the plus side, unlike naive assembly/C, Python auto-promotes integers to bignums instead of overflowing when your numbers are bigger than 2**32.

Answer (score 5):

The basic answer to your question is this, multiplication using `*` is handled through C code. In essence if you write something in pure python its going to be slower than the C implementation, let me give you an example.

The `operator.mul` function is implemented in C, but a `lambda` is implemented in Python, we're going to try to find the product of all the numbers in an array using `functools.reduce` and we are going to use two cases, one using `operator.mul` and another using a `lambda` which both do the same thing (on the surface):

```
from timeit import timeit
setup = """
from functools import reduce
from operator import mul
"""

print(timeit('reduce(mul, range(1, 10))', setup=setup))
print(timeit('reduce(lambda x, y: x * y, range(1, 10))', setup=setup))
```

Output:

```
1.48362842561
2.67425475375
```

`operator.mul` takes less time, as you can see.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to actual multiplication. The multiplication is done by the same builtin code in both places. Your just changing the overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, functional programming involving many computations is best made to take less time using *memoization* -- the basic idea is that if you feed a true function (something that always evaluates the same result for a given argument) the same thing twice or more, you're wasting time, time that could easily be saved by identifying common calls and storing whatever they evaluate down to into a hash table or other quickly-accessible object. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization for basic theory. It is well-implemented in Common Lisp.